# How to calculate sample size in a dataset with multiple tests

Tags: r, sample-size, statistical-power

I need some help. I just cannot figure it out on my own.

I got told to find out if we already have enough participants (birds) for this study, so doing a power analysis to calculate the sample size. 
However I just cannot figure out how it works, because all examples I found only have two groups, while I have six.

We have 6 different tests that each bird has to do. We want to compare the results between the different tests eventually. So I wrote down the 6 tests in R like this:

```
a = c(0,75,300, 0,0)
b = c(550, 500, 1025, 575, 200)
ab = c(0, 675, 225, 400, 75)
r = c(0, 575, 975, 600, 0, 0)
cmin = c(0,0,350,75, 0)
cplus = c(1000,550, 1050, 650, 500)
```

This is the data that I have to work with and somehow I need to calculate the sample size for this. 
If anyone understands what I mean and could help me, that would be highly appreciated!

Comment: The Power Analysis depends on the statistical analysis you are going to perform do you know which one it will be?

Comment: Probably some ANOVA's